# How can I generate a route with javascript variables in Symfony?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, routes

I try to use javascript routing in Symfony according to this tutorial:  https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html

Here is my code:

```
...
  "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
  return Routing.generate('get-file', { fileId: data });

}
...
```

Amd the scripts:

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('get-file', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
<script>
const routes = require('../../public/js/fos_js_routes.json');
import Routing from '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js';

Routing.setRoutingData(routes);
Routing.generate('rep_log_list');
</script>
```

But I get the error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some
>   mandatory parameters are missing ("fileId") to generate a URL for
>   route "get-file".").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a bundle to do that.
Generate the route with a default parameter, then replace it with your JavaScript variable.

```
let route = "{{ path('get-file', { filedId: 'fileId_' }) }}";
route = route.replace('fileId_', yourVariable);
```